# Using jquery ajax xml to update td cell input fields

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I've got a dynamic table generated server side with cells containing some HTML markup, input fields, as well as plain text. I also have a slider widget which allows the user to add a percent to the numbers in the cells. The slider makes an ajax call which returns a valid XML file containing one node for each cell (td) in the table. All this is working fine.

The problem is I'm not sure how to loop through both the XML and the cells at the same time. I'm at the point where retrieving the XML data is working fine.

```
$('#point_value').live("change", function(){
    var this_sct=$(".program_grid");

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"ajax/points_update.php",
        data:{
            pr_id:$("#programid").val(),
            point:$("#point_value").val(),
            calc_lease_amount:$("#calc_lease_amount").val(),
            calc_lease_amount_extra_dollar:$("#calc_lease_amount_extra_dollar").val()
        },
        context:document.body,
        dataType:"xml",
        success:function(xml){
            $(xml).find('payment').each(function(){
            ... this is where the code needs to loop through each <td>
            ... and update the existing values with the new XML values

            >> doesn't work >> $(this_sct).next('input[name^="elb"]').val($(this).find("payment_h").text());                

            ... replace dynamically named input 'elb##' value with new number
            ... each <td> will have an input  field needing to be updated
            ...   <td><input name='elb1' value='123.45'></td>
            ...   <td><input name='elb2' value='419.11'></td>

        }
    });
});
```

I've tried updating the `<input>` by `find`ing an input starting with 'elb' and changing its .val() to the "payment_h" text() field from the XML.

XML Sample file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<program>
<payment>
    <payment_h>3018.48</payment_h>
    <payment_l>2018.48</payment_l>
    <bo_1>100.62</bo_1>
    <bo_2>17.45</bo_2>
</payment>
<payment>
    <payment_h>2269.74</payment_h>
    <payment_l>1269.74</payment_l>
    <bo_1>75.66</bo_1>
    <bo_2>13.12</bo_2>
</payment>
<payment>
    <payment_h>1897.20</payment_h>
    <payment_l>897.20</payment_l>
    <bo_1>63.24</bo_1>
    <bo_2>10.97</bo_2>
</payment>
</program>
```

HTML Sample file

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>row 1</th>
    <td><input type="hidden" name='elb7' value='123.45'>123.45</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name='elb8' value='823.15'>823.15</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name='elb9' value='1123.95'>1123.95</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <th>row 2</th>
    <td><input type="hidden" name='elb10' value='2123.45'>2123.45</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name='elb11' value='3123.45'>3123.45</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name='elb12' value='4123.45'>4123.45</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

I'm close, but need some direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not really clear what you try to do. There some details missing. What is the rule to for relate xml payment to td? Same position of td as payment or something else?

Comment: When the XML data is retrieved, I need to take the first node of data, and insert it into the first <td> in the table, the second node to the second <td>. I am able to loop through the XML data with the `.each()` function, but need to simultaneously move from cell to cell until all xml nodes have been used and all cells have been updated.

Comment: Question, do you also wish to change the text following the input field? i.e. `value='123.45'>123.45</td>` change both 123.45 values?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in favor or `.on()` - for newer jQuery versions

Comment: Yes, I will be changing both values (inside the input, and text in cell). I figured once I was able to change one of them, I could figure out the other fairly simple. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `.on()` vs `.live()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are quite close (I nearly can't believe this is this easy). 
Change your success function as following:

```
   success:function(xml){
                var pos =0;
                $(xml).find('payment').each(function(){
                    var e = $(this_sct).find('input[name^="elb"]')[pos];
                    $(e).val($(this).find("payment_h").text());
                    pos++;
                })
```

There are some improvement possible but this should show the way. This assumes that "this_sct" is the parent tr element to the td which should be changed.

Comment: this seems to make sense to me also :) - although I would probably add a class to the inputs and access them by index within all inputs of that class.

Comment: Close, but the `pos` variable will change, and not always be 0. However, that gets me thinking that if I could choose the first `pos` of the table's `<td>` then I could take it from there. Oh, and no, the "this_sct" is the parent `<div>` housing this table as well as other elements. Thoughts?

Comment: I fail to see what you mean. If the number td with input is the same as the pyment entries in xml this should do. If there other rules please add this to your question.

Comment: D'oh! You're absolutely correct. When I tested it I was merely looking at the screen representation of the text, not the "hidden" input value. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit shorter:

```
success : function(xml){
    $(xml).find('payment').find("payment_h").each(function(ind){
         $('input[name^="elb"]').eq(ind).val($(this).text());
    });
}
```

Comment: And thank you, too! I actually will be using a combination of yours and the "accepted" answer (simply because hr_117 got in first).